# Add nicked player to Scoreboard team

Tags: bukkit

I managed to change the skin of a player and it's name. But now I have a new problem: I work with Scoreboard Teams for the PlayerList and OverHead name. Now I add the name of the fake player to the team. The name over it's head changes to '"§a" + name', but in the TAB-list, there is a white name of the fake player. Every player can see, that this is a fake player.

Comment: Can you how the code used to put the player in a team and color its name?

Comment: Create team:
`GameManager.sb = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager().getNewScoreboard();`

`Team player = GameManager.sb.registerNewTeam("Player");`

`player.setPrefix("§a");`

Add entry:
`GameManager.sb.getTeam("Player").addEntry(nickName);`

Answer (score 0):

I think that using setPrefix might be your problem. In vanilla, you set the color, not the prefix. It might be interpreting it as a literal string, but that's my only guess. You should try to find a setColor() method for the team. I've been trying to create fake players for a very long time, could you toss me the code for it?

Comment: It is not very hard to do...
Hope this thread woll help you. I have 70% of my code out of this: http://postcrafter.de/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=2387

Comment: Is there anything in English?

Comment: I don't think so... you have to search by yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add them with there nickname is what i'm guessing your saying

you will need to do this.

```
PLAYER_VARIABLE.getCustomName();
```

and that method returns there name

Comment: From `getCustomName` documentation: "This value has no effect on players, they will always use their real name."